# wcf architecture

Tags: c#, wcf

What I need:

a listener that can accept HTTP messages that contain information in the URL parameter. The listener needs to *send* the data from the parameters to another part of my app (another project).

What I already know:

I think that creating a WCF service is the best way to go but I don't see how I would structure it. Do I need 2 services - one that accepts the HTTP messages and one that sends the information to my app?

I want to make the HTTP listener another project since I think it can be reused by other applications.

Comment: How first part must send data to another part of your app?

Comment: in the most efficient/easy way. Both are .net applications that run on the same server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way for .Net interprocess communication now is to use WCF.

Since you are going to have to implement a WCF service in your second project anyway (to listen for passed parameters from your HTTP listener), you might as well just listen directly in that project IMHO.

There seems little point in creating a separate listener unless this listener is also going to talk to different apps at the same time (ie a single input point for external clients).

**EDIT**: to better explain:

```
What you propose:

          HTTP listener app             Other app
--HTTP--> WCF service       -----IPC--> WCF service


What I propose:

          Other app         
--HTTP--> WCF service
```

Comment: The issue is that I don't know how to best pass the data from the listener to my other project (which doesn't contain a wcf service)

Comment: That's what I'm saying, you should pass data via WCF. You other project will need to implement a service anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the first WCF service from the client and from the first service you can internally make a proxy object for second wcf serivce and call the WCF service from the first service and recieve the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a wcf service for listen to http and then depend to your second project it can call a wcf service or can insert data to db of second project or can send data by query string or post data to second project.